# Swagger Azure AD OAuth2 token isn't used

Tags: c#, swagger, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to use AzureAD to get a token in swagger and test my controllers with it.

Here I'm logging with swagger-ui:

[image]

And just after this without use my personnal AzureAD Id, I'm already logged.

But when I try to use my controllers, I have the Error: `Unauthorized`

My controllers all inherit from a baseController. All of them have the  [Authorize] annotation.

I don't really know where is the problem.
I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v2.5.0

Some config code.

Statup.cs

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = "{client_id}";
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}";
            });
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info
        {
            Title = "API",
            Version = "v2",
            Description = "Api Help",
            Contact = new Contact()
            {
                Name = "John Doe",
                Email = "john.doe@somewhere.com"
            }
        });
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

        options.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new OAuth2Scheme()
        {
            Flow = "implicit",
            Type = "oauth2",
            TokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token",
            Description = "OAuth2 Implicit Grant",
            AuthorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize",
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "user_impersonation", "Access api" }
            }
        });

        options.OperationFilter<FileOperation>();
        options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API V2");
        c.RoutePrefix = "Help";
        c.OAuthClientId("{client_id_swagger_app}"); //Swagger
        //c.OAuthClientId("client_id_api_app"); //api
        c.DisplayRequestDuration();
        c.OAuthClientSecret("{secret_client_key_swagger}"); //swagger secret
        c.OAuthAppName("Swagger");
        c.OAuthRealm("http://localhost:1234/swagger/ui/o2c-html");
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        c.OAuthUseBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant();
        c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "resource", "{app_ID_URI}"} //api
        });
    });

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Are you using Swashbuckle?

Comment: Can you share a link to your API?

Comment: it's local i don't have any. Why do you need a link ?

Comment: If you provided the correct {client_id} and {client_key} this should work that's why I would like to see your API in action... what happens when you click on the [Authorize] in the UI?

Comment: a tab opens and closes instantly, then the "Authorize" button transforms in "Logout", which is normal, i guess.
Swagger doesn't use anything to connect. 'curl -X GET "http://localhost:1234/Account" -H "accept: application/json" '

Comment: Look here: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index Do you have the locks next to the endpoint like that one?

Comment: You don't need to specify a client secret by the way. Implicit grant does not use it.

Comment: Have you configured authentication on your API properly? I can't see it from your code.

Comment: @HelderSepu I don't have these locks.

Comment: @juunas yes, when i used Postman i can access my route, and retrieve the token from Azure AD.
I update the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured Swagger UI to get an access token with the resource:

```
c.OAuthAdditionalQueryStringParams(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "resource", "{app_ID_URI}"} //api
    });
```

But you have configured your valid audience as:

```
options.Audience = "{client_id}";
```

Swagger UI using the App ID URI is fine, and you can instead configure your API to accept both the client id and URI as audiences (Azure AD allows using both, so why not configure your API as such too?):

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudiences = new List<string>{ "client-id", "app-id-uri"}
};
```

The above should go in your `AddJwtBearer` configuration callback, and you can remove the `options.Audience =` line.

To specify scopes required per action, you need to add an operation filter inside `services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>{})`:

```
options.OperationFilter<AuthenticationOperationFilter>();
```

And define the filter that requires the OAuth scope on every action:

```
public class AuthenticationOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
        {
            new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                //Note "OAuth2" casing here must match the definition you use in Swagger UI config
                ["OAuth2"] = new List<string>{ "user_impersonation" }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What you have defined in the Swagger UI configuration defines what scopes the user can select when using the UI.
Bear in mind that since you are using Azure AD v1 endpoints, what scopes you select will not matter.
The token will always contain the scopes which have been consented, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: it doesn't fix my actual problem but thanks, i dont have the locks next to my endpoints, i thinks thats my error

Comment: Ahh, I suppose it hasn't added the security requirements for the endpoints?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add an example of that after lunch :)

Comment: I added a reduced example of the operation filter I am using currently to show how you add the requirement to the API actions.

Comment: I got my locks, but when i click on them after logging, the "Available authorizations" is empty. Is that normal ?
And I still have the Unauthorized error

Comment: Ahh, it could be that you need to set the key to have identical casing, so change `oauth2` to `OAuth2` in the filter.

Comment: Yes ! that's it ! Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: Awesome, I updated the answer to include that info too